# Changing selection image with custom table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've got a custom UITableViewCell with a custom background image.. How would I change that image upon selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know which cell it is because you have an indexpath.
You know that cell has some imageview with your image on it.
So the only thing you have to do is find that cell change the image to the one you want and update the tableview.

Something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.myCustomImageView.image = myNewImage.

    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting selectedBackgroundView for the [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: i've tried cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"listBackgroundSelected.png"]];   ... but it's not working

Comment: Did u do anything with contentView of the tableview cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and just change your image inside.